# view timing out but same query is fine in a new query window

Tags: sql-server

I am looking at a query for a colleague.

When I execute the view he has made it returns a time out message. However if I execute the exact same query in a new query it executes fine, although it does take approx 45 seconds. Why does the view not return any data? Is there a default timeout period for views in SQL server 2012?

Comment: Is the colleague accessing the view from something other than SSMS (e.g. through another application)? Most *client* access libraries (e.g. ADO .NET) offer some form of timeout functionality and it's there you'd have to look.

Comment: No we are both accessing it through SQL Server management studio

Comment: Can you post the view code? How long does the query take to run when not in the view?

Comment: Well, there is an execution timeout option in SSMS (Tools -> Options -> Query Execution, see Execution time-out) but in a default setup it's 0 (no time-out)

Comment: as Damien pointed out,there is no time out in SSMS,query runs until you stop.Can you share more details as others suggested